# How do I make a timer function in Python that allows another function to stop the timer when a certain event is run?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a small game I'm working on.

I want a timer to run simultaneously as a constantly updating `timeRemaining` variable if a certain event, such as a correct answer is called. If not, it should continue until 0.

How do I write a function to stop the timer if said event is called?

I tried using Timer from the threading library built into python, but I still seem to not be able to find a comprehensive answer.